# Serverless can't fetch all records Event object failed validation?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I am trying to fetch all records using query and JSON schema but I am keep getting `Event object failed validation` unless I pass a query it didn't give me any result.
I am trying to fetch all the records that have `status=OPEN`
I set the default value of `status=OPEN` but it looks like default value is working.
Unless I pass the `status=OPEN` as a query
Please help me!!!

And used `@middy/validator` for this case anyone it's been 2 days I still can't figured out the problem

### JSON Schema file

```
const getAuctionsSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['queryStringParameters'],
    properties: {
        queryStringParameters: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['status'],
            properties: {
                status: {
                    default: 'OPEN',
                    enum: ['OPEN', 'CLOSED'],
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

module.exports = getAuctionsSchema;
```

### Here all records fetch file

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const validator = require('@middy/validator');
const commonMiddleware = require('../lib/commonMiddleware');
const getAuctionsSchema = require('../lib/schemas/getAuctionsSchema');

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const get_auctions = async (event) => {
    const { status } = event.queryStringParameters;
    let auctions;

    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName: 'statusAndEndDate',
        KeyConditionExpression: '#status = :status',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':status': status,
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#status': 'status',
        },
    };

    try {
        const result = await dynamoDB.query(params).promise();

        auctions = result.Items;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new createError.InternalServerError(err);
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(auctions),
    };
};

module.exports = {
    handler: commonMiddleware(get_auctions).use(
        validator({
            inputSchema: getAuctionsSchema,
            ajvOptions: {
                useDefaults: true,
                strict: false,
            },
        })
    ),
};
```

### Here is the error I can see in Cloud Watch

```
ERROR   BadRequestError: Event object failed validation
at createError (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/util/index.js:259:10)
    at validatorMiddlewareBefore (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/validator/index.js:55:21)
    at runMiddlewares (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.js:120:88)
    at async runRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.js:80:5) {
  details: [
    {
      instancePath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/required',
      keyword: 'required',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'must have required property queryStringParameters'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What was the URL that your client requested? Did it have any query parameters?

Comment: @jarmod Yes there is query parameter  called OPEN and CLOSED. To be accurate my problem is that i want query parameter should be default OPEN like if i don't pass any query  the default query should be OPEN that's what I want if pass the query its working but want if I don't pass anything the default query should work

Comment: You misread my question. It seems that you want an optional query parameter named `status` (whose default value will be OPEN) but in your actual test you did not provide any query parameters and hence you failed the schema validation per the answer below.

Comment: @jarmod I don't know much about because I am still learning. Yes maybe you are right can you tell mw how to do If I don't pass status as a query like physically typing but it still  it still gonna status=OPEN as a default query

Comment: You first have to resolve the schema validation problem if you want to allow no query parameters so try the suggestion in the @eli6 answer.

Comment: @DeveloperNans I added an example in my answer for how you can set the status value to open, even if queryStringParameter is null in the query. Please see the 'EDIT' below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The validator is expecting a `queryStringParameters` property of type `object`. According to the [JSON Schema Specification for Objects](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html), if a property is declared as having a certain type, that property fails validation if it is has a different type.

If you don't pass any query parameters to Api Gateway (in a Lambda Proxy integration), queryStringParameters will be `null`, but you have specified that it must be an object and [null is not an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).

It is possible to specify several allowed types in the Schema: `type: ['object', 'null']`. You can read more about using several types [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html#type).

---

EDIT:
To be able to set `status` to 'OPEN' even when `queryStringParameters` is `null` in the query, you can give `queryStringParameters` a default value (an object), with `status` set to 'OPEN'):

```
const getAuctionsSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['queryStringParameters'],
    properties: {
        queryStringParameters: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['status'],
            default: {status: 'OPEN'},
            properties: {
                status: {
                    default: 'OPEN',
                    enum: ['OPEN', 'CLOSED'],
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```